# Setting EditText imeOptions to actionNext has no effect

Tags: android, android-layout, focus, ime

I have a fairly complex (not really) xml layout file. One of the views is a LinearLayout (`v1`) with two children: an EditText(`v2`) and another LinearLayout(`v3`). The child LinearLayout in turn has an EditText(`v4`) and an ImageView(`v5`).

For EditText v2 I have imeOptions as

```
android:imeOptions="actionNext"
```

But when I run the app, the keyboard's `return` does not check to `next` and I want it to change to `next`. How do I fix this problem?

Also, when user clicks next, I want focus to go to EditText v4. I do I do this?

For those who really need to see some code:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/do_txt_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/col6"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/gm_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/coldo_text"
            android:hint="@string/enter_title"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textColor="pigc7"
            android:textSize="ads2" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/rev_text"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/coldo_text"
                android:hint="@string/enter_msg"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textColor="pigc7"
                android:textSize="ads2" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/colbtn_r”
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick=“clickAct”
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/abcat” />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I'm not sure this will work for views that are not siblings, but you can try adding `android:nextFocusDown="@id/edit_text_v4"` (also maybe try `android:nextFocusForward` or some of the other nextFocus attributes).

Comment: @Karakuri it didn't work. Notice that the next button is not showing up at all. The button is still the return button.

Comment: @KatedralPillon Did you manage to solve it ? If yes then can u post your solution here ? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 225):

Just add `android:maxLines="1" & android:inputType="text"` to your EditText. It will work!! :)

Comment: doesn't work in my case. :\ `<EditText
                android:id="@+id/loginEmail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:hint="username"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:nextFocusDown="@+id/loginPassword"/>`

Comment: Try setting your EditText's height as wrap_content.

Comment: @TeodorKolev Try setting your EditText's height as wrap_content.

Comment: Not working also with `wrap_content `. Setting an `inputType` solved the problem in my case.

Comment: This works, but now the EditText scrolls to the right instead of going to the next line automaticly when it hits the right side of the screen. I would like the Edit text to scroll vertically instead and start on a new line when it runs out of space. How do I do this?

Comment: @Janneman96 Did u try setting inputType ="text" and android:singleLine="true"?

Comment: I ended up writing 
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="text" and writing 
        mEditTextAnswer.setHorizontallyScrolling(false); and 
        mEditTextAnswer.setLines(6); inside the onCreate

Comment: use `android:maxLines="1"` instead of `android:singleLine="true"` as its deprecated

Comment: android:maxLines="1" android:lines="1" android:imeOptions="actionNext"
Its not working

Comment: Although,` android:singleLine="true"` is deprecated but some how does the trick, while `maxLine="1"` does not working.

Comment: You must set the inputType="text" to make imeoptions work.

Comment: It is actually mandatory to add `inputType` attribute for this to work. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: what if your input type is numeric?!!??!?!

Comment: @manfcas setting an inputType worked for me, thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 51):

`singleLine` is deprecated. Adding an input type (eg: `android:inputType="text"`) also worked for me.

Use `android:maxLines="1"` as `singleLine` is deprecated

Comment: This is the correct answer!! imeOptions and maxLines will have no effect without inputType

Answer (score 43):

`android:singleLine` has been deprecated, it is better to combine `android:maxLines="1"` with `android:inputType="text"`. This would be the code:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:inputType="text"
        />
```

Answer (score 31):

The answers given here were all very helpful, but I was still struggling to get my keyboard's "Next" to show.

**Turns out that when you use Android's `android:digits` attribute in your XML, it prevents the `android:imeOptions="actionNext"` from working as expected.**

The answer is actually to use the deprecated `android:singleLine="True"`. This seems to force the IME Option to be respected.

Old, Non-Working Code

```
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/first_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ- "
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:hint="@string/first_name"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:maxLength="35"
            android:maxLines="1" />
```

Working Code

```
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/first_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ- "
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:hint="@string/first_name"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:maxLength="35"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true" />
```

I'm not a fan of using a deprecated attribute, but for now it seems to get the desired result.

Comment: thanks deprecated but it's working !!
any issue will occur in future?

Answer (score 13):

single line deprecated so you add below code I think inputType must.

```
        <EditText 
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext" />
```

Answer (score 11):

Finally i have got sure solution for this issue 
Just add these **3 lines** in your edit text and it will be working fine

```
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

Here you can add **maxLines** according to your requirement. **Do not** use **singleLine** as it is deprecated now.
Good luck!

Answer (score 10):

These three lines are enough.

```
android:singleLine="true"
android:inputType="text"
android:imeOptions="actionNext"
```

Comment: android:singleLine="true" has been deprecated since  API Level 15 (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#singleLine) Please use android:maxLines="1" instead.

Answer (score 8):

```
android:inputType="text"
```

You have to specify an inputType in order for imeOptions to function.

Comment: what if the last item is password in form?

Answer (score 7):

below code is force

```
android:inputType="text"
```

Answer (score 6):

Only this worked for me.

Change it:

```
android:maxLines="1"
android:inputType="text"
android:imeOptions="actionNext"
```

on that:

```
android:singleLine="true"
android:inputType="text"
android:imeOptions="actionNext"
```

Comment: inputType="text" did it for me.

Answer (score 5):

Key here is to set input type and imeOptions attributes

```
<EditText 
   android:inputType="number"
   android:maxLines="1"
   android:imeOptions="actionSearch" />
```

Answer (score 5):

Only put in your EditText xml

```
android:inputType="text"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/auth_register_re_password"
    android:hint="Enter Password Again"
    android:imeActionLabel="login"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:maxLines="1"/>
```

Comment: what does `actionUnspecified` do exactly.

Answer (score 0):

> Add this following lines to in your EditText.

```
<Edittext
android:layout_height = "match_parent"
android:layout_widht = "match_parent"
android:inputType="text"
android:maxLines="1"
android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
android:imeActionLabel="Search"
android:hint = "Search Here" />
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Observation that i saw for this:
When you call implicit keyboard for a particular input, the android checks whether keyboard was called for same input box previously or not.

If called for same input box just show the previous ime option for that input box or else check the ime option that is currently set and use it.

There is some kind of caching which is creating the problem.