# EditText | Android TV | Softkeyboard

Tags: android, xml, android-softkeyboard, android-tv

I have tried many different ways to get **NEXT** button on the keyboard, but nothing worked.

Below are few Stackoverflow links i have followed.

1. [Setting EditText imeOptions to actionNext has no effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23036890/setting-edittext-imeoptions-to-actionnext-has-no-effect)
2. [imeOptions "actionNext" programmatically - how to jump to next field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459168/imeoptions-actionnext-programmatically-how-to-jump-to-next-field/3459208)

I have seen few Android TV application, using below keyboard for inputs.

[image]

Any idea how can i get it?

**EDIT:**

Here is my XML

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etNric"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/three_hundred"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/hint_nirc"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:minLines="1"
    android:nextFocusDown="@id/etCaptcha" />
```

Comment: can you post your xml where you have implemented imeOptions ?

Comment: @Umair please check edited question

Comment: check my answer your main problem is with the assigning id ... :)

Answer (score 1):

you need to have to use `android:nextFocusForward` by the way you are also giving the id in a wrong way. and I believe the real problem is also with that way of giving id. although you can use `nextFocusDown` too

Use `@+id/` instead of `@id/`

```
android:imeOptions="actionNext"
android:nextFocusForward="@+id/yourNextEdittext"
```

And you need to specify the `inputType="yourInputType"` also to make an edittext work.

Comment: Hi @Umair, Thanks for answering this question, but its not working. Have you tried this on Android TV application ? I think it might be working on Android App

Comment: @AbdulAleem I have implemented the same on Kiosks but yes not on TV application but i believe the syntax and working for this will be the same.

Comment: @AbdulAleem and also one more thing have to tried using it while giving inputType too ? I think that's needed too for it to work :)

Comment: what input type you want me to try ? i have tried "text" but not working

Comment: @AbdulAleem it wired that it's not working. have you tried giving these attributes in code instead of xml ?

Comment: Nah, i have not tried giving these attributes in code. I will try it :)